# Scandir without file extensions

Tags: php, scandir

How do I get the files displaying without the file extension?
Currently I get a file like `logo.png` but I only need the file name `logo`.

```
if (is_dir($dir_path)) {

    $files = scandir($dir_path);

    foreach($files as $file) {

        if ( !in_array( $file, $exclude_all ) ) {

            $path_to_file = $dir_path . $file;
            $extension = pathinfo ( $path_to_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
            $file_url = $dir_url . $file;

            echo 'Path to file: ' . $path_to_file . '<br />';
            echo 'Extension: ' . $extension . '<br />';         
            echo 'URL: ' . $file_url . '<br />';

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since PHP 5.2.0 `pathinfo` can do that as well:

```
$bareName = pathinfo($path_to_file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = "filename.test.php";

echo substr($text, 0, strrpos($text, ".")); //filename.test
```